# How to display all values of an array into different input text areas?

Tags: jquery

I have an array of objects having some questions and answers. The jQuery code shows the values of array outside the input fields but not inside it.

I have searched for the solution but did not get it.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1> Press 'Enter' after writing your answer. </h1>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" id="output" />
    <input type="text" id="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" id="output" />
    <input type="text" id="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" id="output" />
    <input type="text" id="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" id="output" />
    <input type="text" id="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" id="output" />
    <a id="sub" href="#"> Submit </a>
    <div id="result"> </div>
</div>
</body>


<script>

$('document').ready(function() {

    let questions = [
        { 
            question: "1. I like tea.",
            answer: "I do not like tea."
        },

        {
            question: "2. You are my friend.",
            answer: "You are not my friend."
        },

        {
            question: "3. She is very naughty.",
            answer: "She is not very naughty"

        },

        {
            question: "4. You can do it.",
            answer: "You cannot do it"

        },

        {
            question: "5. They are good.",
            answer: "They are not good."

        },

    ];

    $.each(questions, function() {

        $('#result').append(this.question + "<br>");

    });

 });

</script>
```

I just want something like  $('#input').append(this.question + "
"); which is, of course, a wrong syntax. 
Could you please help me with the right code ?

Comment: Please do not have the same ID in multiple elements, the ID should always be unique

Comment: Not only *should* the `id` be unique, it **must** be unique.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly your desired result looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$.each(questions, function(i,x) {

    $('.input').eq(i).val(x.question);
    $('.output').eq(i).val(x.answer);

});
```

Please note that you should never have multiple elements with the same ID, but you can instead use classes for this.

I've changed your ID's to Classes, like `id="input"` to `class="input"`

**Demo**

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

    let questions = [
        { 
            question: "1. I like tea.",
            answer: "I do not like tea."
        },

        {
            question: "2. You are my friend.",
            answer: "You are not my friend."
        },

        {
            question: "3. She is very naughty.",
            answer: "She is not very naughty"

        },

        {
            question: "4. You can do it.",
            answer: "You cannot do it"

        },

        {
            question: "5. They are good.",
            answer: "They are not good."

        },

    ];

    $.each(questions, function(i,x) {

        $('.input').eq(i).val(x.question);
        $('.output').eq(i).val(x.answer);

    });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <h1> Press 'Enter' after writing your answer. </h1>
    <input type="text" class="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" class="output" />
    <input type="text" class="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" class="output" />
    <input type="text" class="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" class="output" />
    <input type="text" class="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" class="output" />
    <input type="text" class="input" name="questions[]" />
    <input type="text" class="output" />
    <a id="sub" href="#"> Submit </a>
    <div id="result"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked great. Please help me a bit more with my next question.

Comment: I cant see that you have posted a new question.

Comment: I am not allowed to post for two days according to rules.

Comment: @TarunRathore First of how could I have known this? Second, if this question is solved please mark it as solved.